# LibreOffice in Ubuntu 16.04 uses all my cpu - very slow scrolling

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, cpu-load

[newbie here] LibreOffice used to run smoothly until recently. Now, with no apparent reason, it uses all my cpu when scrolling and writing comments. It's slow and lagging. Any thoughts, advices etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic does happen! Updated libreoffice. Removed a language pack(italian) I installed before the problem appeared. Result: magic! It works just fine, as before. No idea how this happened.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the anti-aliasing which is slowing your scrolling.

For me, it slowed the rendering of horizontal lines such as the manual page breaks and the header and footer separators in an extreme way.

Going to [Menu -> Tools -> Options -> Libreoffice -> View] and disabling anti-aliasing solved the issue for me, day and night.